# app Generic Names in Gnome 3 panel and menu

Tags: gnome3, application

For my grandparents' desktop, I need to show the generic names for apps in the activities menu and panel. I am using gnome 3. Is there a way to do this, maybe in gsettings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Menu Editor - menulibre. Works on more than GNOME.